# Unix Command to Search a text pattern

Tags: regex, unix, command, pattern-matching

Im trying to search a text like this below in my log files in Unix box i.e. it starts with text 'TransactionTime:' and then after some characters there is a bracker [ with some numbers inside and then closed by ]

For e.g.

```
TransactionTime: 1407258546484 -> 1407258552848 [ 6364 ]
```

I tried a couple of combinations to search this in my unix file using Grep but it didnt help me, how can i search and print all these lines in my console or output file ?

File name is TransactionPerformance.log

Thanks

Comment: You want extract any text or just search for the whole line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below grep command which use `-P`(*Perl regexp*) parameter,

```
grep -P '^TransactionTime:.*?\[[\s\d]+\]' *
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of choice I would try `ack` an improved version of grep -> [enter link description here](http://beyondgrep.com/why-ack/)

```
ack '^TransactionTime:.*\[ [\d]+ \]' *
```